# Get the id and title of custom post type for send notifications with FCM

Tags: php, wordpress, firebase-cloud-messaging, custom-post-type

I have the following [function](https://github.com/jedrivisser/wordpress-fcm-plugin) that when I have a new post, I get the ID to get the title of the post and then use it to send it as a notification (Using Firebase Cloud Messaging). But these only work for `POST`.

```php
function send_message_on_publish($ID, $post) {
    include('inc/functions.php');

    $title = 'New post!';
    $msgtext = $post->post_title;

    send_push($msgtext, $title);
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'send_message_on_publish', 10, 2 );
```

But I need to use this same function for a CUSTOM POST TYPE (`post_type=tribe_events`), how could I get the ID and title of a post_type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [`publish_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) hook which is quite literally only when a `post`'s post status is changed to `publish`.

To answer your question specifically, WordPress has a dynamic hook for [`{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/new_status_post-post_type/). Simply add the action hook:

```
add_action( 'publish_tribe_events', 'send_message_on_publish', 10, 2 );
```

And it should fire for your `tribe_events` post type as well. Custom Post Types still have an `ID` and `post_title` record that's accessible identically to standard `post`s.

```
function send_message_on_publish($ID, $post) {
    include('inc/functions.php');

    $title = 'New post!';
    $msgtext = $post->post_title;

    send_push($msgtext, $title);
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'send_message_on_publish', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'publish_tribe_events', 'send_message_on_publish', 10, 2 );
```

With all that said, you may want to consider using [Post Status Transitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) instead, because `publish_{$post_type}` hooks will run when the `post_type` is first published *and* when it's updated.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I tried but it didn't work for me. My custom post types (tribe_events) is this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/

Comment: It worked, only it took a while to get notification. Thank you.